# How to synchronize system time on servers upon network connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, time, windows-domain

I have 9 servers that have windows server installed on them, and have been set to synch with windows time server. They are expected to join a domain network (that at the moment has 4 servers) at a later date. (At the moment the network needs a switch with more ports for all of the servers). The problem is that the servers may be headless by the time they are ready to join the network (no monitor). Because of this, the date and time will be different, and remote desktop (the only way to access the servers) will fail because of the time difference on the certificate.

How can I force the servers on the network to refresh their system time and date automatically upon loading (with no login)? Windows automatically sets next synch to be several months later.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the server to sync the system time and date by running `w32tm /resync`.

You could write a batch script that contains this command, and have it triggered by Task Scheduler.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426113/2845411) on StackOverflow contains such a batch script, which is designed to be triggered on system startup.